# Menu item not visible

Tags: android, menu, menuitem

I am doing menu item. But i am not able to view the menu item in the screen. What need to be done to view the Menu item. My code:

```
            public boolean onCreateOptionMenu(Menu menu){
      super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

       int group1 = 1;
       int group2 = 2;

      MenuItem info = menu.add(group1,1,1,"About");
      info.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
      MenuItem set = menu.add(group2,2,2,"App Setting");
      set.setIcon(R.drawable.images);

       return true;
      }


         private boolean MenuChoice(MenuItem item){

            switch(item.getItemId()){
                case 1:
                Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked on item 1",    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
        }

       return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too... It was due in my case to the fact that the images were saved in the folder "`drawable`". I moved them to the "`drawable-hdpi`" one and the problem was solved! Cheers.

Comment: And there is a bug that can cause the first drawable in the "Drawable" folder not to be drawn, to fix it, add a dummy drawable like aaadummy.xml in the folder. Maby they have fixed it now, but I always throw it in there just to be sure :) , and image files should always be added to a density bucket folder like "drawable-hdpi", Only add .xml files in the "drawable" folder like Shapes and Selectors. happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    Log.d(TAG, "CreateMenu");

     MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
     inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);
       return true;


}



@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{    

        switch(item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.x:

            Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked on item 1",    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)         }
                        break;
                    }


    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing Menu Inflater:

```
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.game_menu, menu);
```

via: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice reference on [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com) about [Menus](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html).

Answer (score 0):

try as after returning `super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)` from `onCreateOptionMenu`

```
 public boolean onCreateOptionMenu(Menu menu){

   int group1 = 1;
   int group2 = 2;

   menu.add(group1,1,1,"About").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
   menu.add(group2,2,2,"App Setting").setIcon(R.drawable.images);

   return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

Look at this example

http://www.androidhive.info/2011/09/how-to-create-android-menus/

Answer (score 0):

Mine was because in styles.xml, parent had a wrong theme.  Make sure it starts with android: Try this:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```